# Check if Semaphore is requested

Tags: c#, multithreading, semaphore

I have one static SemaphoreSlim variable:

```
static SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
```

I can Wait() and Release() the semaphore.

But if the semaphore is aquired by a Task, how can I see if it is requested by a different task?

Comment: Question: I have `class C { public static int x = 3; }`  Suppose thread Alpha decrements C to 2, and will increment it at some point in the future. How can thread Beta know that thread Alpha decremented a variable in the past and will increment it in the future?

Comment: You can use `.WaitOne(Int32)` overload to wait for the semaphore a specified amount of time (in milliseconds).

Comment: Why do you care?

Comment: If a task want's to enter its critical section, the other task should leave its critical section.

Comment: Why? Thats not the semaphore purpose. Its purpose is to guarantee only 1 thread (or more, depend how you created the c# semaphore) is entering a shared code and resources, and other threads will wait till he finish. The thread is not aware about other threads wishes to enter the "critical section" - just to prevent from them to enter.

Comment: What structure do you advise for my situation? I now use a Cancellation Token which is working.

Comment: It depend on what the "critical section" does and by your application design..